# how to get end of month before from yesterday date

Tags: php

I need to get yesterday date and 6 end of month date before from yesterday..
what i do is :

```
$yesterday_day = date("d") - 1;
$yesterday_month = date("m");
$yesterday_year = date("Y");
$yesterday_date = date("m/d/Y", mktime(0,0,0,$yesterday_month,$yesterday_day,$yesterday_year));

$day_before_1 = date("d") - 1;
$month_before_1 = date("m")-1;
$year_before_1 = date("Y");
$date_before_1 = date("m/t/Y", mktime(0,0,0,$month_before_1,$day_before_1,$year_before_1));
```

when i `echo` its fine for yesterday date is always right.. but strange thing happen on end of month before when i try to change my pc date to 31 march 2014(or 30 March). End of month before should be 28 Feb 2014 but its show 31 march 2014.. its normal if i choose from 29 March and before..

i suspect its because Feb just got 28 days but dont know how to solve this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i resolve this problem. The idea is simple, still using srttotime but i dont use -x month.. Instead i use -x day.. code behind will show it :

```
$yesterday_day  = date("d")-1;
$yesterday_month = date("m");
$yesterday_year  = date("Y");
//getting yesterday date
$date_query = date("m/d/Y", mktime (0,0,0, $yesterday_month, $yesterday_day, $yesterday_year));

$day_before = date("d");
if($day_before==1){
 $day_before =substr($date_query,3,2)+1;
}

$date_query_before_1 = date("m/d/Y",strtotime("-$day_before day"));

//to get number of day in that month using substr
$day_before += substr($date_query_before_1,3,2);
$date_query_before_2 = date("m/d/Y",strtotime("-$day_before day"));


$day_before += substr($date_query_before_2,3,2); 
$date_query_before_3 = date("m/d/Y",strtotime("-$day_before day"));


$day_before += substr($date_query_before_3,3,2);
$date_query_before_4 = date("m/d/Y",strtotime("-$day_before day"));


$day_before += substr($date_query_before_4,3,2);
$date_query_before_5 = date("m/d/Y",strtotime("-$day_before day"));


$day_before += substr($date_query_before_5,3,2);
$date_query_before_6 = date("m/d/Y",strtotime("-$day_before day"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), Luke.
It will give you required timestamp for next usage as 2nd parameter to date function.

Comment: how about giving $day_before_1 = 1;

Comment: if i change to $day_before_1 = 1; it will normal for 31 march but when i change pc date to 1 March 2014 Last End of month will 28 Feb 2014.. it should be 1 month before yesterday which is 31 Jan 2014...